# Why the app can't get arabic words from json file with flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, firebase-storage

I have this json file I uploaded on firebase storage containing Arabic words, but when I try to access it using http.get(url) and print the response or build it with Text() it gives me these weird

**characters:**

```
Ø¨Ø³Ù Ù±ÙÙÙ Ù±ÙØ±Ø­ÙÙ Ù±ÙØ±Ø­ÙÙ
```

what I expect is `بسم ٱلله ٱلرحمن ٱلرحيم`

**Code:**

```
final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final _store = Firestore.instance;
  String khatma;
  String link;
  var data;

  down_data() async {
    final user = await _auth.currentUser();
    await _store.collection('users').document(user.uid).get().then(
          (value) => {
            setState(
              () {
                khatma = value.data['Joined'];
              },
            ),
          },
        );
  }

  Future getAya() async {
    await down_data();
    if (khatma == 'Khatma 1') {
      var response = await http.get(
        'firebase link',
      );
      data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(data);
    }
  }
```

**json file:**

```
{
  "verse_1": {
   "Aya": "بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ",
   "taken": false
  },
  "verse_2": {
   "Aya": "بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ",
   "taken": true
  }
}
```

Comment: as i can see `Ø¨Ø³Ù Ù±ÙÙÙ Ù±ÙØ±Ø­ÙÙ Ù±ÙØ±Ø­ÙÙ` is `iso-8859-15`(may be) encoding of the string `بسم ٱلله ٱلرحمن ٱلرحيم`, you have to use utf-8

Comment: how ? see I am new in coding.

Comment: are you setting the json values from your code? if so share it if not please share the json file

Comment: no it is completely separate

Comment: Must I download notepad++ ?

Comment: and if I converted it to UTF-8, will it work fine with json decoding or there is another way ?

Comment: it should work definitely

Comment: can u post an answer ?

Comment: but when I open it, it says that it is already UTF-8

Comment: it didn't work.

Comment: you are http.get ing the file right?, post what print(data) does

Comment: yes I am get, post doesn't get the the file at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
///first decode the response to utf-8 string
var myDataString = utf8.decode(responseAsBytes);
///obtain json from string
var myDataJson = jsonDecode(myDataString);
```

Comment: one thing, how can the text widget wait until I get this text, I used Futurebuilder, but it gives me this error Failed assertion ..... data != null

Answer (score 2):

thank you Yadu,, its work now

```
Future<Item?> getItemAPIUTF8() async {
final url =
    "https://..";
http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  // var data = json.decode(response.body);

  var data1 = utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes);
  var data = jsonDecode(data1);
  print(response.statusCode.toString());
  return itemAPI.value = Item.fromJson(data);
}
return null;
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31174061)